# Taking the unique values to a dataframe Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a dataframe in the following format.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | abc |
| 123 | xyz |
| 111 | abc |
| 456 | abc |
| 456 | xyz |
| 456 | pqr |

I want to derive a dataframe as follows from the above dataset.

| abc | xyz | pqr | abc, xyz | abc, xyz, pqr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 |  |  | 123 | 456 |

This is more like a combination problem but in Pandas,

Comment: Could there be another row with, say `112` in `Col1` and `abc` in `Col2`, and no other row with `112` in `Col1`?

Comment: Btw.: Have you ever upvoted and/or accepted any answers that you got? Might help in incentivicing useres to help you.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can start by using a `groupby` on Col1, joining all the elements of Col2, and creating a `pivot_table` on the result converting, Col2 elements as columns:

```
out = df.groupby('Col1',as_index=False)\
    .agg({'Col2':lambda x: ','.join(list(x))})\
            .pivot_table(columns='Col2',aggfunc='first')

print(out)

Col2  abc  abc,xyz  abc,xyz,pqr
Col1  111      123          456
```

Then, you can add the additional columns by comparing which columns are in your new dataframe and the unique values of your original df2:

```
out[[x for x in df.Col2.unique() if x not in out.columns]] = np.nan
```

The result will be:

```
print(out)

Col2  abc  abc,xyz  abc,xyz,pqr  xyz  pqr
Col1  111      123          456  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I have around 7mn rows. Is there any faster method?

Comment: This is only giving the first occurrence from the Col1. I need all the occurrences.